# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to develop a sample spring boot application that has spring JPA and Hibernate implementation. While I managed to get my setup complete, I am getting the following error while running the application.

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'

I suspect this is some kind of configuration based error, but I am unable to pin point the source of the error.

I have seen some posts with this error and tried those resolutions. But those didn't help me resolve the error.

Here is my application's setup.

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shandesh</groupId>
    <artifactId>training</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml file :-

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    username: ****
    password: ****

  jpa:
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

Entity class :-

```
package com.shandesh.dao;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPUSER")
public class AppUserDTO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    Long userId;

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    String userName;

    @Column(name = "USER_FIRST_NAME")
    String userFirstName;

    @Column(name = "USER_LAST_NAME")
    String userLastName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    Timestamp lastUpdatedDate;
}
```

Repository class :-

```
package com.shandesh.repository;

import com.shandesh.dao.AppUserDTO;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUserDTO, Integer> {

    List<AppUserDTO> findByUserName(String userName);
    List<AppUserDTO> findByUserId(Integer userId);
    List<AppUserDTO> findAll();

    @Modifying
    Long deleteByUserName(String userName);

    @Modifying
    Long deleteByUserid(Integer userId);

}
```

Service class :-

```
package com.shandesh.service;

import com.shandesh.dao.AppUserDTO;
import com.shandesh.repository.AppUserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class AppUserService {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    public List<AppUserDTO> getAllAppUsers() {
        return appUserRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Controller class :-

```
package com.shandesh.controller;

import com.shandesh.dao.AppUserDTO;
import com.shandesh.service.AppUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration //(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserService appUserService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<AppUserDTO> getAllUsers() { return appUserService.getAllAppUsers(); }

}
```

Stack trace while running the application via IntelliJ console.

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50180:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre\lib\rt.jar;G:\Shantanu\Learning\Technology\Projects\training\target\classes;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.1\log4j-api-2.11.1.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.7\jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.7\jackson-core-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.7\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.7\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.7\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.12\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.13.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.4\ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.2\aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.3\javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.1.2.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.6.0\HikariCP-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.1.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.1.2.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.16\lombok-1.16.16.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.7.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.23.1-GA\javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.3\byte-buddy-1.9.3.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.1.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar;C:\Users\Shantanu.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.3.7.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.7.Final.jar" com.shandesh.Application

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-07-11 10:12:12.575  INFO 5872 --- [           main] com.shandesh.Application                 : Starting Application on SKD-PC with PID 5872 (G:\Shantanu\Learning\Technology\Projects\training\target\classes started by Shantanu in G:\Shantanu\Learning\Technology\Projects\training)
2019-07-11 10:12:12.582  INFO 5872 --- [           main] com.shandesh.Application                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-11 10:12:13.827  INFO 5872 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-07-11 10:12:13.925  INFO 5872 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 86ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-07-11 10:12:14.778  INFO 5872 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf78f5b2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-07-11 10:12:15.211  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-07-11 10:12:15.230  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.231  INFO 5872 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-07-11 10:12:15.238  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.5].
2019-07-11 10:12:15.238  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2019-07-11 10:12:15.238  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.242  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.396  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-11 10:12:15.396  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2735 ms
2019-07-11 10:12:15.434  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.439  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.440  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.440  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.440  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.481  WARN 5872 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2019-07-11 10:12:15.484  INFO 5872 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-07-11 10:12:15.523  INFO 5872 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-11 10:12:15.531 ERROR 5872 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Process finished with exit code 1

I am hoping that this application would run successfully and I would be able to see JSON output of all user entries with https://localhost:8080/getAllUsers.

Comment: are there any stacktrace ?

Comment: have you tried excluding HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class in @EnableAutoConfiguration?

Comment: Hello @ShanDesh Please share stack trace and also note that you don't need to use ResponseBody Annotation with RestController as it is active by default. Change Return Type of  getAllUsers() from Object to List<AppUserDTO>

Comment: I think ```deleteAppUserDTOByUserName``` make it problem with look up unknown property as AppUserDTO. Fix it to ```deleteByUserName```.

Comment: can you share complete logs?

Comment: Its tough to say without the logs if this is what is causing the problem, but I am guessing your `spring.datasource.url` value is not in alignment with the oracle thin style syntax. I would try `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl` more explanation here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA

Comment: Just remove **AppUserDTO** part from `find` method names and `delete` method names in your `AppUserRepository`.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by you all, including changes to yml file syntax. But I still get the same error. I will post stack trace as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`findAppUserDTOSByUserName(String userName)`, `findAppUserDTOSByUserId(Integer userId);`

To

`findByUserName(String userName)`, `findByUserId(Integer userId);`

> The query builder mechanism built into Spring Data repository
>   infrastructure is useful for building constraining queries over
>   entities of the repository. The mechanism strips the prefixes `find…By`,
>   `read…By`, `query…By`, `count…By`, and `get…By` from the method and starts
>   parsing the rest of it. The introducing clause can contain further
>   expressions such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to
>   be created.

Also, note that you don't need to use `@ResponseBody` with `@RestController` as it is active by default. Change Return Type of `getAllUsers()` `from Object to List<AppUserDTO>`